# Android Studio Google Auto login (without button)

Tags: android

I was creating a quiz game.. which is the best way to auto login to gmail account when the game starts? I want that when the game starts, to check if the gmail is connected and if not to auto connect, then to restore the level from online database maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think the Android system automatically calls Google services completely
Here is an article from Google that will help you in this regard :

[https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart](http://Google%20Game)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the player is already logged in or not:

```
private boolean isSignedIn() {
  return GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this) != null;
}
```

You can call silentSignIn() to retrieve the currently signed-in player’s account, and try to sign players in without displaying a user interface if they have successfully signed in to your app on a different device.

```
private void signInSilently() {
  GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
      GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
  signInClient.silentSignIn().addOnCompleteListener(this,
      new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
          if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // The signed in account is stored in the task's result.
            GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
          } else {
            // Player will need to sign-in explicitly using via UI
          }
        }
      });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  signInSilently();
}
```

Call getSigninIntent() on the GoogleSignInClient to obtain a sign-in intent, then call startActivity() and pass in that intent. The following code snippet shows how your app can launch an interactive sign-in flow:

```
private void startSignInIntent() {
  GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
      GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
  Intent intent = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
  startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

In the onActivityResult() callback, handle the result from the returned intent.

If the sign-in result was successful, get the GoogleSignInAccount object from the GoogleSignInResult.
If sign-in result was not successful, you should handle the sign-in error (for example, by displaying an error message in an alert). The following code snippet shows how your app can handle the results of player sign-in:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
      // The signed in account is stored in the result.
      GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
    } else {
      String message = result.getStatus().getStatusMessage();
      if (message == null || message.isEmpty()) {
        message = getString(R.string.signin_other_error);
      }
      new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage(message)
          .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, null).show();
    }
  }
}
```

> Providing a sign-in button

To provide a standard Google sign-in button in your game, you can use one of these approaches:

Include a com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton on the main activity layout; or
Design a custom sign-in button according to the Google Sign-In branding guidelines.
When users click the sign-in button, your game should initiate the sign-in flow by sending a sign-in intent, as described in Performing interactive sign-in.

This code snippet shows how you can add a sign-in button in the onCreate() method for your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
  findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
  findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

> The following code snippet shows how you can send the sign-in intent
>   when the user clicks on the sign-in button.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button) {
    // start the asynchronous sign in flow
    startSignInIntent();
  } else if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_out_button) {
    // sign out.
    signOut();
    // show sign-in button, hide the sign-out button
    findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button).setVisibility(View.GONE);
  }
}
```

> Signing the player out

```
private void signOut() {
  GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,
      GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
  signInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
      new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
          // at this point, the user is signed out.
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: You must activate Google Play features in Google Platform to activate these features
You can follow one of the annotations in YouTube to enable it

Comment: i do this and i let you know.. so you think the load/save could be with play services without firebase?

Comment: i try all but nothink :/